# How to write a superscript Registered ® in product name

Tags: magento-1.9, product, frontend

Our customer wants to offer several products which are registered trademarks. We included the (R) sign in the according product names. Unfortunately, they are not shown superscript as the customer wishes them to be. Now we just tried to use the `<sup>` tags to make the sign superscript. Those HTML tags are removed from the string which leads to no change.

How can we put a superscript ® in the product name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. At least not in a quick and simple way. 
Probably the only way to accomplish this is to dive in to the `catalog/product/view.phtml` and around line 51 replace

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

for

```
<h1><?php echo str_replace('&reg;', '<sup>&reg;</sup>', $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')) ?></h1>
```

It's a bit dirty in my opinion but will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A colleague lead me to an other, JavaScript-based solution that i'll post here as an answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

We solved it also in another, less invasive way as it is only important for presentation purposes to have the sign superscript. So we included the following JavaScript snippet that replaces all occurrences of ® with `<sup>®</sup>`:

```
   String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore)
{
    return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignore?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

         var n=jQuery("body").html().replaceAll('®','<sup>®</sup>');
        jQuery("body").html(n);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It will help to write the superscript registered in product name in magento.
    - Place code into $(document).ready, it's works fine

```
$('body :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
   return this.nodeValue.replace(/[™®©]/g, '<sup>$&</sup>');
});
```